# Chrome driver unable to Identify Alert Message box

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I am using Selenium Chrome Driver to test my application.

There is one page in the Browser where on Load an Alert message appears and I have to Click **OK**.

The problem is when I try to use `driver.SwitchTo().Alert` in my code. The Alert appears on the foreground page while the page is still loading. When I continue to debug at this point, my driver waits for an infinite time, and when I click manually on OK button, then it tries to `switchto().alert`, but since there is no Alert, it fails.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Note: The Page is in Loading Form till I click on Ok button on Alert , I wonder if it is alert

I also followed the below solution , but it does not work for me 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/CixorzKZE4E

I get the following exception , 
he HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL localhost:3200/session/0285afd8049f70878988405463448d24/… timed out after 60 seconds.

I can still see alert on my child window .

Answer (score 0):

you could use explicit wait for the loading part.ie if webdriver instance is driver

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, //mention the time as per need here ie 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("mention the url"));
```

before the alert handling code.

Comment: it is not any specific URL , this happens when I navigate from parent window to child window

Comment: you could try with other expected conditions i.e. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) .Also you could refer this [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)  for available expected conditions in explicit wait. Also, it would be helpful if u could able to update your question with exceptions you can getting with existing code.

Comment: I used the following code   { WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Helper.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent()); }  I still get the exception in the question

Comment: Any luck?if not please share your application url so that issue can be reproduced.

Comment: There was no luck , Unfortunately this was happening in Chrome , when I run the same application in IE or Edge  . I have read in few blogs that the alert is not being identified in Child window for both FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: My approach was to check the element is displayed on page , if it is not visible then I am assuming that the alert is not visible , I cannot share URL of my application as it is secured client

Comment: when I run the same application in IE or Edge it works absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

you need to accept or dismiss the alert, code you can try :

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I get this exception message , when using this                                
          The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL 
 http://localhost:3200/session/0285afd8049f70878988405463448d24/alert_text timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: Still the alert is visible on page

Comment: I tried this before clicking on alert driver.SwitchTo().Window(Helper.driver.CurrentWindowHandle)  , also tried to getpagetitle , it still get this  The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:3200/session/0285afd8049f70878988405463448d24/title timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: Update the question with exception

Answer (score -1):

I find out that the alert was a Javascript alert and how to handle javascript alerts is mentioned in [Selenium Documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows).